# How to generalize these linq queries

Tags: c#, linq

I Have this method:

```
 public IEnumerable<PackModel> PackLookup(short? society, string description)
        {
            return this.context.Pack.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(description) &&
                                                                        (!society.HasValue || x.Society == society))
                                                                       .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
                                                                       .Take(this.max);
        }

        public IEnumerable<FeaturesModel> FeaturesLookup(short? society, string description)
        {
            return this.context.Features.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(description) &&
                                                                    (!society.HasValue || x.Society == society))
                                                            .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
                                                            .Take(this.max);
        }

        public IEnumerable<ConstraintsModel> ConstraintsLookup(short? society, string description)
        {
            return this.context.Constraints.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(description) &&
                                                                    (!society.HasValue || x.Society == society))
                                                            .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
                                                            .Take(this.max);
        }
```

The three methods are very similar, only the DbSet changes, how could I make these calls in a generic way to avoid code duplication

Comment: Do the entities for Features, Constraints and Pack all share the same base type or interface?

Comment: The entities all share the same interface

Comment: Use interfaces and extensions for them. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66754046/3133328

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all your entity models share the same interface that has properties for `Description`, `Code` and `Society`, then you can abstract away using the [`Set<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Set__1_System_String_) method of your DbContext and a [generic type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), for example:

```
public IEnumerable<TModel> Lookup<TModel>(short? society, string description)
    where TModel : class, IYourInterface
{
    return this.context.Set<TModel>()
        .Where(x => x.Description.Contains(description) &&
                    (!society.HasValue || x.Society == society))
        .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
        .Take(this.max);
}
```

Now you call it like this:

```
var results = Lookup<PackModel>("society", "description");
var results = Lookup<FeaturesModel>("society", "description");
var results = Lookup<ConstraintsModel>("society", "description");
```

Comment: Set<TModel> It gives me the error The type 'TModel' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.set<TEntity>()'

Comment: Oops, I forgot that EF requires the `class` constraint too, I've added that.